# Got "Cannot be resolved to a type" in iReport for expression with static method

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I created one Java program and create jar file for that program in the program class name is `DateFormate` and static method is `demo()`

Then added that jar file to iReport file then i call that *static* method as

```
new com.it.DateFormate.demo()
```

then this error raised:

```
com.it.DateFormate cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: Error messages should be part of the question, as text.  Please don't use screenshots to show us error messages.  Use copy-and-paste.

Comment: There may be a problem with your project setup.  You probably haven't correctly told the IDE where to find `com.it.DateFormate`.  However, since we have almost no information about the problem, there's no way to help you any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a static method the call will be

```
com.it.DateFormate.demo()
```

Hence, no <s>new</s>

To make it work the class needs to be in `classpath`, if you like it to work inside of your IDE make sure you add a jar (to the IDE) that contains this class.